# Required symbol * based on condition

Tags: php, yii

Does anyone know how to add * symbol to form field on certain condition in Yii. I have a field phone ,which is present only when user location is india.so the user with location India logged in ,the field Phone number should be shown with * symbol

```
array('phone','required','on'=>'create'),
```

But my textfield displays only when location is india.ie,

```
<?php

 if ($result->location=="india) {
 echo $form->textAreaRow($model, 'phone', array('class' => 'span7', 'rows' => 4,));

}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: i have done using scenario,ie array('phone','required',on=>'create').but my problem is that the field phone will not present always.it will be active only when location is india

Comment: Add the code to the question. Bot in the comments.

Comment: @user3807139 This might be helpful: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/9205-difrent-validation-rules-depending-on-selected-options/

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom validation rule, maybe something like this :

```
private $_country;

public function rules()
{
   return array(
        array('other_field, one_more_field', 'required'),
        array('phone', 'safe'),
        array('phone', 'requiredInIndia'),
    );
}

public function requiredInIndia($attribute, $params)
{
    if(!empty($this->phone))  
    {     
        if($this->country === 'IND')
        {
            $this->addError($attribute, 'Dude ! we need your phone number !');
        }
    }
 }

public function setCountry()
{
    // maybe from user ip address if you don't want to relate it to other attribute
    $user_ip = CHttpRequest::getUserHostAddress();
    $this->_country = some_fonction_to_get_country_iso_from_ip($user_ip);
}

public function getCountry()
{
    return $this->_country;
}
```

Then use `$your_model->country` value to print manually the `*` symbol in your view if it satisfy the looked for countries.